# Calling Map on a model object not returning anything

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am having an issue with transforming my model object in an Ember application.

I have a `calendar` route which defines a model like so.

```
this.store.findAll('competency');
```

I am trying to transform the data returned from this in a controller method `calendarItems` which is defined as a property.

What I would like to do is take my model and call the map function on it, transform the object and return it back as a property.

I have changed the controller to a ArrayController to allow Enumberable methods to be called but still no luck. The function is present when I can `this.get('model').map`

Any ideas where I am tripping up? Maybe my approach is way out but basically I just want to transform am model and present that data to the template.

Thanks in advance!
Ryan

**Edit**

This is my transform logic but the array that is logged in the template is just [].

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  calendarItems: Ember.computed('model', function () {
    return this.get('model').map(function(competency) {
      return 1;
    }, this);
  })
});

console.log(this.get('model').get('length'));
```

returns 0 which made me assume I have no model items from the store to iterate one which would explain the blank array. However if I place an `{{#each}}` in the template to print out the models I am receiving 3 models.

**Edit**

**Calendar Route**

```
model: 
  return this.store.findAll('competency');
}
```

**Calendar Controller**

```
calendarItems: Ember.computed('model', function () {
  return this.get('model').map(function(competency) {
    return 1;
  }, this);
})
```

**Calendar Template**

```
{{log calendarItems}}
```

Comment: You need to provide the transformation logic that you have in `calendarItems` or else there's no way to know what you got wrong.  
Also, `store.findAll` already returns an Enumerable so making it an `ArrayController` is detrimental since they're removed in Ember 2.0.

Comment: I have added the calendarItems transform in the main question body but still receiving a blank array.

Comment: `console.log(this.get('model').get('length'));` in the method returns 0 so I am assuming maybe my model setup is not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two major options.

**First**, a computed property in model. Example from docs:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr(),
  lastName: DS.attr(),

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});
```

In template you may use it like this:

```
{{#each model as |item|}}
  {{item.fullName}}
{{/each}}
```

**Second**, computed property in controller, based on model. Example of a controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  something: Ember.computed('model', function () {
    var ret = [];
    this.get('model').forEach(function(item) {
      ret.push(item.get('something'));
    }, this);

    return ret;
  })
});
```

Example of template:

```
{{#each something as |item|}}
  {{item}}
{{/each}}
```

**Also**, you can define a helper, pass each item to it and return what you need. More about this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235795/where-and-how-to-include-ember-model-functions/32236385#32236385)

Comment: Thanks, I have come to the conclusion that my model is not present or loaded in the controller. I set up the `calendar` route by `return this.store.findAll('competency');` but in the `calendar` controller `console.log(this.get('model').get('length'));` returns 0 when there is three items

Comment: Please use Ember Inspector to view what do you have in store http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/ember-inspector/installation/

Comment: Also I suggest to look into console for errors and look request to backend and response on "network" tab in developer tools

Comment: Thanks, no errors in the console and have 3 competency models in the store

Comment: I also receive all the models in the network request as expected.

Comment: Sounds good. Put `console.log('computing!'); console.log(this.get('model'), this.model);` in your computed property and look at output in console

Comment: Looks as expected to me. `Class {store: Class, isLoaded: true, manager: Class, isUpdating: true, __ember1441141826237: null…} Class {store: Class, isLoaded: true, manager: Class, isUpdating: true, __ember1441141826237: null…}` However isUpdating seems strange.

Comment: Also the `computing!` is present in the console.

Comment: Put also `{{log calendarItems}}` in template. I just tried similar code (computed property using map) and it works perfectly.

Comment: I get `[]` regardless of the map it seems that the this.model is not populated with store items.

Comment: Could you please post your route, controller, model and template?

Comment: added at the bottom of original post.

Comment: `model: 
  return this.store.findAll('competency');
}` looks like typo, it should be `model: function () {
  return this.store.findAll('competency');
}`. Try `console.log(competency);` before `return 1;` inside map callback

Comment: Sorry this is a typo when I copied it in, the function is actually present in the code. No iterations of the map are executed as the model has a length of 0

Comment: You extending an `Ember.Controller` or `Ember.ArrayController`? Should be first

Comment: If you put in template `{{#each model as |item|}}{{log item}}{{/each}}`, do you see all 3 items in console?

Comment: Yes get 3 of `Class {store: Class, container: Container, _internalModel: InternalModel, isError: false, error: null…}`

Comment: In this case I don't see any reasons why your computed property doesn't work. Must be a typo somewhere in your code. Take a break an re-check things later. Sometimes this helps to notice cause of problem.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your help! I'll have a look tomorrow.

Comment: I have re-done all the model, route, controllers etc with the CLI and for it is now working. I must have generated something incorrectly. Thanks for your time with this, your tips helped my get to the source of the problem.